# How can I customize Window.Confirm() dialog in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var val= confirm("Are you sure to cancel?");
```

By default, the above line of code will bring a popup with two choices, Ok, Cancel and Ok will be the default choice. I want change the default choice to be Cancel and I would like to swap the both button's position. So Cancel will be displaying first and Ok comes later.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you do not use jquery dialog, instead?

Comment: You can't, dialogs like `confirm` and `alert` are built into the browser and use native OS stylings.

Comment: Is there a way we can do it in javascript?

Comment: No, JavaScript cannot affect those dialogs. They are a part of the browser UI, not the webpage.

Comment: Can someone suggest how can i achieve using jquery?

Comment: @Hello123 Look at the link that André posted to someone else who asked this same question and got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible if this behaviour is important I would look for a JavaScript library that achieves what you want for instance http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals